# code not working despite following exact instructions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming with Javascript, and I am building a simple ping-pong game with the help of a video. I have followed every instruction in the video yet it doesn't seem to be working. **ballX** is supposed to reset in the middle once it goes past the canvas width, but the **X** is supposed to reverse if it hits the right paddle.

```
if (ballX < 0) {
  if (ballY > paddle1Y &&
    ballY < paddle1Y + paddleHeight) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
  if (ballX > canvas.width) {
    if (ballY > paddle2Y &&
      ballY < paddleHeight + paddle2Y) {
      ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
    } else {
      ballReset();
    }
  }
}; //ends movement();
```

Comment: And what is currently happening? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: if ballX is not less than zero, then you never check if ballX > canvas.width ... you have a misplaced `}` - you also have a `;` after a `}` that is not required

Comment: I have formatted your code to fix the indenting (*no* change to anything else) so that it is now readable, but still it is not very clear what it is trying to do without more context.

Comment: just goes to show how *proper* indentation can help solve code bugs

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct your if structure to:

```
// if ballX is less than 0, expected to use is paddle1
if (ballX < 0) {
  if (ballY > paddle1Y &&
    ballY < paddle1Y + paddleHeight) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
}
// else if ballX is in the other side of the table, expected to use is paddle2
else if (ballX > canvas.width) {
  if (ballY > paddle2Y &&
    ballY < paddleHeight + paddle2Y) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
}
```

Your **};** was misplaced.

Comment: the if statement is correct, the position of the `}` was wrong :p

Comment: Right. Forgot to specifically mention that. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Moved `}` - see if that helps

```
if (ballX < 0) {
  if (ballY > paddle1Y &&
    ballY < paddle1Y + paddleHeight) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
} // added
if (ballX > canvas.width) { // this probably should be an else if but it really doesn't matter
  if (ballY > paddle2Y &&
    ballY < paddleHeight + paddle2Y) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
  // a } removed from here
} //ends movement();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ballX` is smaller than 0 then it will never be larger than the canvas width, quite simply making that portion of code useless. The logic simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it could be some parenthesis issues.

```
if (ballX < 0) {
  if ((ballY > paddle1Y) &&
    ((ballY < paddle1Y) + paddleHeight))) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
} // added
if (ballX > canvas.width) { // this probably should be an else if but it really doesn't matter
  if ((ballY > paddle2Y) &&
    ((ballY < paddleHeight) + paddle2Y))) {
    ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
  } else {
    ballReset();
  }
  // a } removed from here
} //ends movement();
```